# what's the exact meaning of :: in Ros( C++ )

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello guys. I'm a beginer in Ros. I read lots of "  ::   " . ex) ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
what's the exact meaning of ::? plz... Im really suffering from it.
and do you think it's better to use c++ than python? can you recommand?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309709/what%27s-the-exact-meaning-of-::-in-ros(-c++-)/) by [Chung Oh](https://answers.ros.org/users/38781/chung-oh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Technically, your question is a C++ question, not a ROS question, and we should be closing this.

But just to point you in the right direction: the double colon (`::`) you see in C++ source code is called the *scope resolution operator*. It is used to tell the compiler in which *scope* the identifier (ie: name of something) that follows can be found.

If you search for "C++ scope resolution operator" you will probably find more than enough information about this (Wikipedia also has a page about it: [wikipedia.org/Scope_resolution_operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chung Oh](https://answers.ros.org/users/38781/chung-oh/) on 2018-12-01**:
Really thanks for your explaination :) hundred percent I got.  Thanks